# Converting hex string to hex integer

Tags: python

I'm having problems converting a hex string like this: `0x187c` to a hex integer without loosing zeros, and converting to integer.

I need the exact hex integer to find USB devices. The hex integers correspond to a vendor and product id.

I am using the following code to find devices:

`dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x187c, idProduct=0x0521)`

The problem is that I need to enter those numbers from a graphical interface.  However, once the user types them I get them back as a string, and the `usb.core` module doesn't find the device.

```
>>> type(0x187c)
<type 'int'>
>>> type("0x187c")
<type 'str'>
>>> type(hex(int("0x187c",16)))
<type 'str'>
```

Is there any way to retrieve this value that will work with `usb.core`?

Comment: are you saying `int('0x187c', 16)` does not suit you? Numbers are numbers. The phrase `...to an hex integer` does not make any sense

Comment: What do you mean "without losing zeros"? Do you want a string that's padded with zeros? Have you tried a format string?

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as 'hex integer'. There is a *hexadecimal notation* to define an integer value, but that's still a *regular integer value* you produce with it. You already managed to convert the string to an integer there, that suffices *just fine* for the `usb.core.find()` method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I thought it was possible because I can not find a way of writing `0x187c` from a string, without transforming to `1313`, and conserving the integer type. usb.core is not recognizing the devices if I dont input `0x187c` as integer. Maybe its a bug of the [version of usb.core](https://www.rsm.website/software/gnu-linux/software/alienware-kbl/development/usr/share/alienware-kbl/usb) that I'm using.

Comment: @rsm:  you are passing it the integer *value* 6268 to the `usb.core.find()` method. Don't confuse the notation with the value. `0x187c` is *syntax*, and still produces 6268. The function `int('187c', 16)` *also* produces that same integer, and will work *just fine* with the same method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was sure of that but after having problems with my code that was the only difference I found when calling the method. I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere in my code... Sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: @rsm: pair it down to the simplest example that still produces the error, then form a question around that. *Test* your assumptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "hex integers". An integer is an integer. It isn't important for your computer if it was originally written in hex, octal, binary or decimal.

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=int(vendor, 16), idProduct=int(product, 16))
```

will simply work.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the call to hex..

```
>>> type(int('0x187c', 16))
<type 'int'>
>>> print 0x187c
6268
>>> print int('0x187c', 16)
6268
>>> print int('0x187c', 16) == 0x187c
True
```

If `int('0x187c', 16)` isn't working then the problem is elsewhere..

Comment: yep, but if you print the number it wont be 0x187c, it will be 6268

Comment: Those two things are the same thing.. Integers are integers. The value can be represented as hex, decimal, binary, etc. But the value is the same. If your function takes an integer then you just need to pass it an integer of the correct value. How you represent it isn't important.

Comment: That's what I thought, but usb.core doesn't find the device

Comment: It will if you pass it int('0x187c', 16)

Comment: Exactly. 0x187c is just another way to write 6268. `usb.core.find(idVendor=6268, idProduct=1313)` does the same thing as `usb.core.find(idVendor=0x187c, idProduct=0x0521)`

Comment: Maybe my usb.core have some problems, but that doesn't works. Thats why I posted the question!

Comment: That's weird. Try `vendor=0x187c; product=0x0521; print(vendor, product); print(usb.core.find(idVendor=vendor, idProduct=product))`. You'll see that the values that usb.core.find gets are the integers 6268 and 1313. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: I'm over python 2.7 but I agree I think that the problem is somewhere else...